# How do i create a three column responsive footer

Tags: css, wordpress

i need assistance trying to build a three column footer in a website with wordpress. I cant seems to get the positioning of the columns right no matter how hard i try. I actually created a child theme to override the original footer that came with the theme. Can somebody help look at my code and kindly profer solutions please

```
    <footer>
    <div id="footerwrap">
        <div id="menu-footer">
            <h3>Links</h3>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/Our-Curriculum/">Our Curriculum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/admission-procedure/">Why Choose us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/apply-online/">Apply Online</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/news/">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/upcoming-events/">Events/Calendar</a></li>
                </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="social-footer">
            <h3>Links</h3>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/Our-Curriculum/">Our Curriculum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/admission-procedure/">admission procedure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/apply-online/">apply online</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/news/">news</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1/vidniel/index.php/upcoming-events/">upcoming events</a></li>
                </ul>

        </div>

        <div id="copyright-footer">

                Copyright &copy <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <a href="www.vidniel.com">vidniel Tech </a>
        </div>


        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

THE CSS

```
#footerwrap{
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

#menu-footer{
    width:30%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}

.clear {clear:both}

#social-footer{
    width:30%;
    float: right;
    display:block;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;

}

#copyright-footer{
    width:30%;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;
}
```

Banky

Comment: you need to elaborate further preferably create a codepen or js fiddle and then describe what is happening.....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but you should be able to overwrite all of your CSS with the below:

```
#footerwrap{
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
#menu-footer, #social-footer, #copyright-footer{
  width:30%;
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
@media (max-width: 750px){
  #menu-footer, #social-footer, #copyright-footer{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
  }
}
```

This includes a media query for smaller screens to stack your footer below 750px.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.hasnt worked though.im trying to overwrite d footer of the tesseract theme using a child theme for my project.i want the footer to be in 3 columns with each of d 3 classes been justified in each of d columns.column 1 will have a vertical menu while 2 will have social and contact links.col 3 will have copyright,Policy & Terms.Right now the 1st 2 columns are superimposed on each other and the 3rd not well positioned.thats my challenge now